# Timer and UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, updatepanel

i'm trying to create a timer in asp.net

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim min As Integer
Dim sec As Integer
Dim hr As Integer
Dim totalTime As Integer
Dim timerStr As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    totalTime = 5340
    hr = Math.Floor(totalTime / 3600)
    min = 30
    sec = totalTime Mod 60
    timerStr = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hr, min, sec)
    label1.Text = timerStr
End Sub


Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Display()
    label1.Text = timerStr
End Sub
Protected Sub Display()
    totalTime -= 1
    hr = Math.Floor(totalTime / 3600)
    sec = totalTime Mod 60
    If sec = 0 Then
        min = (totalTime / 60) Mod 60
    End If
    timerStr = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", hr, min, sec)
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Display()
    label1.Text = timerStr
End Sub
End Class
```

//update panel code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
    RenderMode="Inline">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

now according to code timer call every second but its not happening i try same with button and click event but still text is not update but page refresh when i hit the button.Am i'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're developing timer for a Web Page - you have to do it on the client-side, using JavaScript, because once server-side code ran and page is rendered to the browser - server-side code finishes and no longer participates in page life.

Here is a simplified example of client-side timer. It has a label (which in browser becomes SPAN) and 2 buttons - to start and stop timer:

```
<span id="Label1" >Seconds: 0</span>

<button id="Button1" onclick="startResetTimer()">Start/Reset</button>
<button id="Button2" onclick="stopTimer()" disabled="disabled">Stop</button>
```

And here is JavaScript code that is responsible for timer:

```
var time; 
var interval;

function startResetTimer() {

    document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = "disabled";
    document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = "";

    time = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        time++;
        document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = "Seconds: " + time
    }, 1000)
}

function stopTimer() {

    document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = "";
    document.getElementById('Button2').disabled = "disabled";

    clearInterval(interval)
}
```

When you click "Start/Reset" button - timer starts via [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) function. When you click "Stop" timer is stopped via [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) function.

You can try a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cg47M/1/), it only displays seconds, but you should get the idea.